# How to interpolate unevenly spaced years in Pandas python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, interpolation

I am trying to interpolate a DataFrame with some uneven years like `orig_years = [2020, 2022, 2030, 2038, 2040]` to something like `given_years = [2020, 2025, 2030, 2035, 2040, 2045, 2050]`.

Here is a dummy DataFrame that I am working on:

```
df:
Out[344]: 
      FUEL  YEAR  VALUE
0      gas  2022   1000
1      gas  2030    500
2      oil  2020      5
3      oil  2040     10
4  biomass  2030    100
5  biomass  2038    100
```

The years are uneven how can I interpolate them? I would appreciate any ideas.

Expected output:
As you see, this is a result of `interpolate(limit_direction = 'both')`

`REGION     FUEL  YEAR    VALUE
0      DE      gas  2020     1000.00
1      DE      oil  2020        5.00
2      FR  biomass  2020      100.00
4      DE      gas  2025      750.00
5      DE      oil  2025        6.25
6      FR  biomass  2025      100.00
..    ...      ...   ...         ...
10     FR  biomass  2035      100.00
11     DE      oil  2035        8.75
12     DE      gas  2035      500.00
14     DE      gas  2040      500.00
15     FR  biomass  2040      100.00
16     DE      oil  2040       10.00`

Thank you.

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Comment: @YOBEN_S I added.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`np.arange`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html)

```py
>>> df.YEAR = np.arange(2020, 2020 + (5*len(df)), 5)
>>> df
      FUEL  YEAR  VALUE
0      gas  2020   1000
1      gas  2025    500
2      oil  2030      5
3      oil  2035     10
4  biomass  2040    100
5  biomass  2045    100
```

Comment: Thanks, but the VALUE is incorrect, e.g: in original DataFrame `oil  2020      5` but that does not exist now. now it moved to 2030.

Comment: can you provide your expected output for same sample data? it would help to better understand qus..

Comment: for example original `oil   2020   5` and for 2025 it should be `oil 2025    6.25` something like that.